# TFS Build Controller and Build Agent

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I'm running a TFS build controller and build agent on the same machine, and I noticed that I don't see the build agent service in the services console. Maybe this is how it is when they are both on the same server, but then according to the practices as outlined in the MSDN regarding TFS, there is supposed to be a TFSService (to run the controller) and TFSBuild (to run the build agent) service accounts, but I don't see a place on where I'm supposed to assign TFSBuild to a service. Where is the build agent service? According to this article, I'm supposed to have two different user accounts: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253149.aspx

[image]

Comment: How did you validate the controller is actually installed on the system? Can you share a screenshot of the tfs admin tool build page?

Comment: Added the screenshot. I did this on a different machine before, but I didn't really fine tune the security before..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All TFS Build components (controller and agents) share the same windows service and service account.  You can see this in the TFS admin console.

Comment: So then what is this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms253149.aspx - talking about?

Comment: That msdn page suggests a single service account (tfsbuild) that is used for the build service.

Comment: Then what is tfsservice for? I only see one service in the services console... according to that article there should be two services.

Comment: Your screenshot shows the proper tab, the first entry is the single Build Service running.  Then at the bottom it shows that you have 1 Controller and 1 Agent running on that Service.  The TFSService account the docs mentions is meant to be used by the Application Tier not the Build Service (which can be on the same machine, but are separate services with separate accounts).